# JavaFX 11 + Eclipse

Tags: java, javafx, eclipse, java-11

Ранее я использовал *Java 8* , где была включена *JavaFX*. Хочу настроить работу *JavaFX 11* используя *Eclipse*

По поводу *JavaFX 11* есть отличное руководство: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Но есть вопросы по разделу *Non-modular projects from IDE* :

**1)** Проект запускается, если в него добавить *User Library "JavaFX11"* и настроить *VM arguments* в *Run Configurations*. Но неужели это нужно делать каждый раз, создавая новый проект? Как понять какие из *modules* для *VM arguments* нужны?

**2)** Возникает проблема с *e(fx)clipse*. После установки как показано здесь (пункты 3,4): https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html *Eclipse* просит перезапуска и во время открытия выдает ошибку, после чего не хочет запускаться вообще:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx об этом предупреждали, мол должна быть версия минимум 3.4.1. Даже ссылку где скачать *e(fx)clipse* дали: https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/3.4.1/site/

Но как этой ссылкой воспользоваться? У меня отображается так (нет дальнейших ссылок или кнопок):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**3)** Пробовал из рабочего проекта сделать .jar файл:

Export... -> Java -> Runnable Jar file

Однако Eclipse предупреждает, что *VM arguments will not be part of the runnable JAR. Arguments can be passed on the command line when launching the JAR*

И соответственно получаю ошибки при попытке запустить такой .jar:

Если использовать *Library handling: Extract required libraries into generated JAR*:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если использовать *Library handling: Package required libraries into generated JAR*:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно в этом случае создать .jar ? (что бы при запуске .jar не передавать аргументы)

Comment: Попробуйте Intellij IDEA, в этой IDE такого гемора нет. В бесплатной версии насколько я помню нет поддержки `CSS`, но она есть в бесплатной 30 дневной версии, но 30 дней это не предел. Йо-хо-хо, кхм.

Comment: Про ограничение на css впервые слышу, вот фишек по спрингу и работе с базой там нет, но если вопрос про eclipse, то врядли в этом плане будет какая-то разница.

Comment: @Bleser , к чему относится Ваше предложение? Intellij IDEA решает все пункты данного вопроса?

Comment: Насколько я понял в IntelliJ IDEA тоже нужно в каждом проекте добавлять библиотеку JavaFX11 и VM options

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на пункт **2)** :

Ссылку, которую советовали использовать https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/3.4.1/site/ нужно применить непосредственно в Eclipse.

Help -> Install New Software...

В поле Work with ввести эту ссылку и нажать Enter. Выбрать компоненты e(fx)clipse, после чего Finish

Теперь можно создавать JavaFX проекты. Но вопросы **1) , 3)** остаются не решенными